# How to set up a checkbox binding in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have a checkbox list, when the user checks one of the checkbox a function is called in the .js file and it in turn calls a method dataservice.js which calls a webapi controller, this all works fine and returns the correct data.

What happens when the process is finished is that the checkbox that fired the sequence isn't checked.  I've inspected the result and schoolDistrict.IsChecked for that item is set to true, which is correct.

How do I get the checkbox to be checked?

Below is the code, but I am unsure about the check.one-way bind

```
<li repeat.for="schoolDistrict of schools.Districts">                                     
  <input type="checkbox" checked.one-way="schoolDistrict.IsChecked" value="${schoolDistrict.Value}" click.trigger="searchSchoolDistrict()"/>${schoolDistrict.Name}
</li>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- The problem is probably that your `searchSchoolDistrict()` code is changing the `IsChecked` property, but the `one-way` binding isn't listening for the change.
- While interpolating the value would work, using the binding syntax is probably better style.
- Setting up a `change.delegate` is more robust, and will listen to all changes on the checkbox, which is a best practice for checkboxes.
- **Deprecated** Make sure you select the proper scope for `searchSchoolDistrict()`, as it probably lives on the `$parent` and not `schoolDistrict`.

Try using this instead:

```
<li repeat.for="schoolDistrict of schools.Districts">                                     
  <input type="checkbox" 
    checked.bind="schoolDistrict.IsChecked" 
    value.one-way="schoolDistrict.Value"
    change.delegate="searchSchoolDistrict()"/>
  ${schoolDistrict.Name}
</li>
```

Comment: if this is helpful, rate and subscribe

Comment: You are quite correct that searchSchoolDistrict is changing the value of IsChecked,. Thank you, that worked a treat.

Comment: thanks for the solution, it helped me as well.
but now i'm a bit confused because $parent shouldn't be necessary anymore, can somebody clarify on that?

Comment: @fops the binding engine was enhanced to search available parents to make using $parent not necessary

Comment: I wasted a long time not realizing that the `click.delegate` function needs to `return true;`.